# how to add a user to local sql server when one has only windows admin rights on the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

I'm in the admin group of a server, but yet I don't have access to the sql server, is there anyway to add myself without the need to reinstall the sql server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do if you are a member of the local Administrators group.

The below steps are taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9889484) on StackOverflow:

Open a command prompt window. If you have a default instance of SQL Server already running, run the following command on the command prompt to stop the SQL Server service:

```
net stop mssqlserver
```

If you're running a named instance of SQL Server, the Service Name will be something similar to `mssql$instancename`.

Open SQL Server Configuration Manager from the Windows Start Menu.  Find the instance listed in the "SQL Server Services" window, and right-click it, then click "Properties".  Go to the "Service Tab", and make note of the "Binary Path" and `CD` into it as such:

```
CD "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn"
```

Run the following command to start SQL Server in single user mode.  As
`SQLCMD` is being specified, only one `SQLCMD` connection can be made (from another command prompt window).

```
sqlservr -m"SQLCMD"
```

Open another command prompt window as the same user as the one that started SQL Server in single user mode above, and in it, run:

```
sqlcmd
```

And press enter. Now you can execute SQL statements against the SQL Server instance running in single user mode.  To add a login for your account, run:

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\USERNAME] FROM WINDOWS;
```

Replace DOMAIN and USERNAME with appropriate values.

```
-- For older versions of SQL Server:
EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'DOMAIN\USERNAME'
     , @rolename = N'sysadmin';

-- For newer versions of SQL Server:
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [DOMAIN\USERNAME];
GO
```

[Source](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11143/how-to-access-a-newly-installed-sql-server-2008-r2-instance-if-you-do-not-know-the-login-and-passwor.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a handy batch file to do it:

admin2sysadmin.bat:

```
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver 
sqlcmd -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

or for a named instance

```
net stop mssql$sqlexpress 
net start mssql$sqlexpress /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssql$sqlexpress
net start mssql$sqlexpress
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

After that the BUILTIN\administrators group will be sysadmins.  If you are a Windows Administrator logged on to the desktop of a machine with User Account Control enabled, you'll have to elevate before being able to connect to SQL Server.  Once you do, you can create a sysadmin login for yourself personally to enable un-elevated local connection.